# Converting a non infinite summation to closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How does one convert
$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i \tag{displayed}$

to its closed form

I know that 
$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}\tag{displayed}$

but I am unsure of how to account for the summation to n instead of to infinity.

Comment: Do you mean closed form?

Comment: @hypergeometric yes sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, by expanding all terms, $$ (1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)=1-x^{n+1}$$ then, by dividing by $(1-x)$ , $x\neq1$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nx^k=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$ and you get the answer.

Comment: so what does that make the flatform...?

Comment: @dbenson See the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that only uses your formula for the infinite sum:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Now:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i + \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i + x^{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$$
and solving for $\sum_{i=0}^n x^i$ and plugging in the first formula yields:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$